# FastAPI Upload multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I'm creating a upload form where I can upload multiple images at once and it's working as long as I POST it with Swagger UI but when I try it with simple HTML form as mentioned in FastAPI [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) I am getting this error `127.0.0.1:55967 - "POST /upload-meme/ProgrammerHumor HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity`.

What am I missing here?

services.py

```
def _is_image(filename: str):
    valid_extensions = (".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif")
    return filename.endswith(valid_extensions)

def upload_image(directory_name: str, image: _fastapi.UploadFile):
    if _is_image(image.filename):
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        image_name = timestr + image.filename.replace(" ", "-")
        with open(f"{directory_name}/{image_name}", "wb+") as image_upload:
            image_upload.write(image.file.read())

        return f"{directory_name}/{image_name}"

    return None
```

**UPDATE:** I tried with response model but now I am getting `404 Not Found` error instead of `{"detail":[{"loc":["body","images"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

main.py

```
    class subreddit(BaseModel):
    subreddit_name: str

@app.get('/')
def index():
    content = """
<body>
<form method="post" action="/upload-meme/memes" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="subreddit_name" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
@app.post('/upload-meme/', response_model=subreddit)
def post_meme(subreddit_name: subreddit = _fastapi.Form(...), images: List[_fastapi.UploadFile] = _fastapi.File(...)):
    for image in images:
        file_path = _service.upload_image(subreddit_name, image)
        if file_path is None:
            return _fastapi.HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="Invalid File Type!")
        return {"filepath": _responses.FileResponse(file_path).path}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Swagger UI doesn't support multiple file uploads in the same form field. So you can not test this using swagger. Build your own UI using html, css and javascript.

Comment: @MazedulIslam Ah! Okay..I didn't know that Thanks for sharing that useful information,so this code of mine in which I implement the multiple files upload serves my purpose,right? It is a Swagger UI issue not the code issue?